# GitHub 2FA: Cannot Add Verification Code to This Account - You already have a code generator

Tags: github

I set up GitHub 2 factor authentication but switched it off in settings. Now I am trying to enable it again within settings but I get this on my iPhone after I scan the QR code.

> **Cannot Add Verification Code to This Account** You already have a code generator for this account. To add a new one, remove the existing
> generator and try again.

I searched and reviewed the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/about-two-factor-authentication) but cannot seem to find a "remove the existing generator". If there is another way to do this without removing the existing generator I would be open to that. I have the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is similar to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/116i252/cannot_add_verification_code_to_this_account/)

> You go to passwords, then <del>Twitter</del> (here GitHub), then where the code is displayed there will be a delete code option.

Also, as [in here](https://twitter.com/ChemCommando/status/1626896875251982337):

> On iPhone, go into password options and select the app you want to use for verification codes after downloading the app, and *before* you do the setup in the Twitter security settings.

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FpPgHDuXoAAVioi?format=jpg&name=small]

Comment: I had to hit edit on the Passwords section of my iPhone to see the remove the code. I did not see it before.

Comment: @lcj That should do it indeed. Well done.